# CountryModel isn't a function, when calling the constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, solid-principles

I have created an abstract class and therein I declared a function, as follows;

```
abstract class Model {
  final String url = '';

  T fromJson<T>(json);
}
```

A class `CountryModel` is implementing it,

```
class CountryModel extends Country implements Model {
  const CountryModel(
      {super.id, super.name, super.countryCode, super.phoneCode});

  static countryFromJson(json) {
    return CountryModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        countryCode: json['code'],
        phoneCode: json['phone_code']);
  }

   
  @override
  CountryModel searchFromJson<CountryModel>(json){

    // This line gives error
    return CountryModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        countryCode: json['code'],
        phoneCode: json['phone_code']);
  }

  @override
  final String url = AppUrls.countrySearch;
}
```

One thing is for sure, that is that passing `ClassModel` to the function as required by the `Model` is causing this.

```
searchFromJson<CountryModel>(json)
```

I found a solution and that is to create another function `countryFromJson` that returns `CountryModel` and that function is returned from `searchFromJson`.

*I want to understand why I'm getting this error, and if there's another fix, so I can get rid of the helper function.*

Comment: `CountryModel searchFromJson<CountryModel>(json)` declares a generic method with a generic type parameter that *happens* to be named `CountryModel`.  It would be no different than if you had written `T searchFromJson<T>(json) { return T(...); }`.  And no, you cannot construct objects of a generic type that way; constructors are not part of a class's interface, and you have no guarantee that the type argument has an unnamed constructor that accepts the specified arguments.

Comment: Makes sense, but what would be a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Take a callback that constructs and returns an object of the desired type.  But really, if you're trying to construct objects from JSON, don't even bother trying to do it yourself and use an existing code-generation-based package, such as [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value).